# character made with multiple objects one armature or different armatures

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

This is a character that I made in Blender with multiple objects 
[image]

When I added an armature fist, and joined the object and test, it didn't work. Then I linked parent but that didn't work either.

What should I do now; I only know how to make models with multiples objects not with modelling. [image]

Comment: Please try to correct punctuations/cases/spellings to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 18):

One way to fix this is to select the object, for example, the arm, and then select the armature. Be sure you take the armature into edit mode and select only the bones you want to have effect on the arm.

Once this is completed, parent the object to the selected bones using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > **With automatic weights**.

Do this same thing for the rest of the model.

**Edit 2:** Here is a step-by-step for applying an armature to separate objects.

**Step 1:** Select the piece you want to be the child of the armature by *right clicking* on it.

[image]

**Step 2:** Select the armature, also by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> and *right clicking* on it.

[image]

**Step 3:** In the bottom left of the 3D viewport, switch to *pose mode*.

[image]

**Step 4:** right click on the bone(s) you want to be the parent of your object.

[image]

**Step 5:** Press <kbd>Ctr</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, then select "with automatic weights.

[image]

that bone is now applied to the object, repeat this method for the rest of the model.