# Linking Bones To Human Model

Tags: bones

In my human walk animation, when I play the animation, only the bones of the human move. How do I link the bones to the body so everything moves together?

Answer (score 3):

This is an addition to @Denis 's answer.

There are other armature deform options, but with automatic weights looks like it's the most reliable with empty groups weights in a close second. It all just depends on how you want your mesh to deform. I made a turkey to show you:

[image]

[here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19656/how-are-bones-armatures-connected-to-the-rest-of-a-model/19658#19658) is the article to look to for a run-down on armatures, by yours truly.

Answer (score 1):

To rig your mesh you need to parent it to armature, select first the mesh, hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the armature, while both are selected hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select automatic weights from the menu. Additional weight painting may be required.