# How to fix armature distorting my mesh?

Tags: mesh, armature

I made a simple model with multiple meshes. One of them is the head The rest is unimportant for this question. The model has one armature which is the parent of the meshes. All the vertices in the head mesh are in one vertex group which has the same name as the head bone. The head mesh has no Mirror modifier. I set the pivot of the head mesh and all the other parts to the middle of the head mesh. I used armature from the `add human (metarig)` command. I applied all locations, scales and rotations. I have no idea what other detail I should supply.

Normally it looks like this:

[image]

However, when I try to rotate the head (not the neck, the head) it looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help me on how to fix this, or should I actually rotate the neck?

Comment: See related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/character-made-with-multiple-objects-one-armature-or-different-armatures/19316#19316

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the distortion may appear, because the vertices of the mesh are improperly assigned to the bone. 
[image]

Select the object you want to be affected by the bone, enter *Edit Mode* and in *Vertex Groups* panel select **neck** group and click ***Remove***.
[image]

Select the **head** group and click ***Assign***.
[image]

The maximum weight of the mesh is assigned to the *head bone*, so now all the vertices will follow the bone completely (you can see the weights entering *Weight Paint* mode).
[image]

Now it should work fine.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for this well-written answer! Exactly this was the problem. I assigned the head, but somehow neck part was assigned too (I made my assignment by putting vertices into groups with the assign button tho').

Comment: You're welcome. Remember that sometimes you have to doublecheck if all the vertex groups are properly assigned to the right bones. Sometimes there are some ridiculous cases, like for example some vertex groups of the leg bone are assigned to the head bone, and when you move the leg it has the influence on the head's movement :D. So it is good to assign the right vertices to the right bone and remove all the other, so they don't affect it.

Answer (score 0):

I have discover a solution for my problem wich I think were very similar,when i rotating head were distorted.It didn't fixed with solution on here and finally discovered that,as I was making squeleton smaller to fit my character... I did apply squeleton transform (would be enough to only scale perhaps,idk) and it fixed it.