# Blender automatic weights distorting mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, weight-painting

I Need help with blender automatic weights. When I click automatic weights it moves parts of the head that doesn't have weights example on the last image, also when I do automatic weights it doesn't cover the correct area for the mesh example image 2.

### Problem 1

[image]

### Problem 2

[image]

Comment: Distortion often appears when the vertices of the mesh are improperly assigned to the bone. It looks like some parts of the head are assigned to the upper arm causing deformation. Please take a look at this answer:
http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21480/how-to-fix-armature-distorting-my-mesh

Comment: Thanks but is there any video to fix this ? thanks

Comment: Sorry, but tutorial requests are off topic (unfortunately) I suggest weight painting by hand... Err.. mouse.

Comment: oh BTW this is the retop , on the original , it works fine =\

Comment: Fix It ^_^ . I just Click Automatic Weights to the Skin Modifier Mesh , and then transfare the weights to the retopo and it worked ^_^ .