# Rigging /My character is breaked/

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

My model normal. Rigging then break and distance.
How i fix?

[image: My normal model]

Breaked and Distance and Location my part of model error.
[image: Breaked and Distance and Location my part of model error.]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "break and distance". I guess you mean the bones are changing position? Maybe it's happening when you change from Object Mode to Pose Mode because you have posed your bones in Pose Mode, but in Edit Mode they are not posed. You can clear the pose and the bones will return to their original position.

Comment: I think @aky-her is right. Assign the hair mesh to the head bone (set the weight value to 1). Check out this related answer also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21480/how-to-fix-armature-distorting-my-mesh Nice model BTW :).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like only the head is moving and hair object stay where it is. If this is the problem, you can easily fix it in weight paint mode by assigning all the hair vertices to the vertex group, which is controlled by your head bone.