# Best way to animate a robot/turret?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, rigging

So I made this:  [image]

Every object is seperate objects (each leg, the main body, the neck, the torso, the head...) and I was wondering if it would be better to rig or to move each piece or something else?

Comment: Copy rotation constraint and a bone

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I'm kinda new to animating, can you expand?

Comment: I would just parent the mesh to bones. see [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/character-made-with-multiple-objects-one-armature-or-different-armatures/19316#19316) post.

Comment: No prob. anything for a fellow chicken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could also use IK-Constraints to control the legs.

Add a plane as *Targets* for each leg so the legs can be moved around with them.   To control the rotation, empties are used as *Pole Targets*

The Legs are parented to the body.

[image]

[image]

[Demo .blend](http://pasteall.org/blend/34193)

[image]

Comment: This is brilliant, but what about the turret, like the OP asked?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise The turret could be another object parented to the 'body', when only rotaion is needed it would not even require another bone. Just keyfamed as is. Perhaps keyframe the intensity of the red 'eye'.

Comment: That makes sense

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways you can do this, but here is how I would do it.

---

First, add an empty:

[image: Add empty]

Now parent all of the objects to it by selecting them, and then selecting the empty and pressing <kbd>Ctrl/kbd>+P</kbd> *> Object*.

[image: Parent to Object]

Now when you move the empty, you should see that your robot follows it. Also there will be lines from the origin of each object to the *Empty*.

---

Now make an armature for each object on your robot:

[image: Armatures]

Now you can select the mesh and add a *Copy Rotation* constraint:

[image: Copy Rotation constraint]

And finally select the armature you want to use:

[image: Select armature]

---

Now when you move the empty, your robot moves, and when you rotate the armature, the object copies that rotation.