# How can I add an 'IK Solver' constraint?

Tags: constraints

I'm just trying to do the beginners tutorial about creating a character and animation of it, it's the well known gingerbread man, but it is written for blender 2.4 and actual version is 2.73 and there are a lot of things which have changed. I have already created the model and just on the way to arrange the bones. I have weight-painted the arms and chest and now I'm in that part to get the feet working

Here is the actual tutorial page I'm working on:
 http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Tutorials/Animation/BSoD/Character_Animation/Lower_body_armature

In pose mode I should add an 'IK Solver' but I cannot find where to add such an constraint and even when I look into the different constraints I cannot find an 'IK Solver'. So this now is the point where I don't know how to go further on, because without this I cannot do entries into that panel and so I cannot go on with finishing the armature and testing it.

Anyone knows how this is to be handled using blender 2.73?
Any help would be appreciated.
BTW sorry for my English as I'm from Austria.
Thx in before for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the *Inverse Kinematics (IK) Constraint* you find it in the properties while in *Pose Mode*.

[image]

You might also be interested in a more recent version of this tutorial: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Your_First_Animation

- [Constraints](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints)
- [IK](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Constraints/Tracking/IK_Solver)

Comment: Thx for your help. But I' searching for the 'IK Solver' The Gingerman already has an Inverse Kinematics added earlier in that Tutorial but now the text days that I have to add an 'IK Solver'

Comment: sorry, input was just broken the exact Text in the Tutorial is :

Comment: @JonnyPoet The UI has changed since version 2.4 there is no longer an option/constraint called IK-solver (which refers to a math-component that does the calculations for IK).

Comment: ' the exact Text in the Tutorial is :     Switch to Pose mode (⇆ Tab).
    Select the lower_leg.l bone.
    Add an IK Solver to lower_leg.l. To do this, in the Constraints panel under the Edit buttons click the Add Constraint button and choose IK Solver. This adds a constraint to the selected bone. Note that in the Constraints panel, there are now settings for the IK Solver constraint. 
The lower_leg.l IK Solver constraint.

Comment: Thx stacker for your response, but how to finish this project?

Comment: You could either try to use the updated version of the tutorial (link is in the post above) or check my answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24181/best-way-to-animate-a-robot-turret (it includes a downloadable .blend) If you actually need to use version 2.4 I've no idea.

Comment: You could also upload your .blend here: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and link it to your question.

Comment: I have just tried what you showed in your picture. Yea to add an Inverse Kinematics was the correct way. !!! Great help!!

Comment: @JonnyPoet You could mark the post then as answered by clicking the checkmark, so other users know that it is solved.

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to sign this post as answered. but cannot find any 'checkmark to do that. Additional how can I rate the persons who helped me?

Comment: @JonnyPoet See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work you can upvote answers as soon you get 50 reputation points.

Comment: Thx for answering all that questions. It has helped a lot