# How do I join bones which have already been parented to different meshes?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a drone model with separate parts. For example, the propeller and the rudder are two separate meshes. I have parented each to individual bones in hope of later joining them into one armature. Unfortunately, when I select all of the bones and hit Ctrl+J, the bones join, but the meshes change position and/or rotation. How do I join the bones into one armature and keep the transformation on the meshes? The reason I want them into one armature is because I plan on putting the drone into BGE.

Here's a link to the blender file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6_5f6jmSaHOa2VaMkVwRzM4UXc

Comment: Did you try parenting the root bones of each part to a (new) single parent bone using the Ctrl-J > Bone option? I think that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that didn't work.

Comment: Make sure to apply rotation and scale to all objects (bones and meshes) before joining, and as @AnthonyForwood said, use another root bone

Comment: @lemon What do you mean by applying rotation and scale? Do you mean adding a keyframe? Also, I'm not sure if this matters, but each part has one bone parented, so each individual bone is its armatures root bone.

Comment: By applying rotation and scale, I mean to be sure all meshes are on the same base (same scale, same rotation). To do this, in object mode, "ctrl + A" (apply) then "rotation and scale". (nothing to do with keyframes). Concerning root bone (adding a bone which is the parent for all), this allow to move the whole and give each part the ability be rotated or move from the referent parent (the root bone), so that your drone has a consistency between all its parts.

Comment: OK, good to read that.. ! Have a nice drone !

Comment: @lemon I actually noticed another problem. Now, when I enter pose mode, if i move the root bone, none of the other boned move, as if they weren't parented. I went back to before I joined the bones, and I made sure they were parented, then applied rotation and scale and then joined the bones again, and same problem...

Comment: I fixed it by simply creating a new armature and following the answer by @ARaddish on this page: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/character-made-with-multiple-objects-one-armature-or-different-armatures