# My mesh freaks out when I rig it, i think because it's made of separate pieces

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones

I'm having a problem with the rigging in my mesh. I made it by adding cubes in edit mode to make the different body parts.

[image: This is my mesh, the arms, legs, body, head, are separate parts. The hair and cap are the same piece but separate from the head]

So anyways, when i made the armature for the mesh, an error popped up. It said "Bone heat weighting: failed to find a solution for one or more bones". I can't manage to make it work.

[image: Here you can see the armature]

In this next picture, i rotated his left leg back 90 degrees and his right leg 45 degrees. The left leg moves both and the right one stretches the body. The head and arms stay where they are no matter what i do, also do the hair and cap

[image: The result of moving the leg bones]

[image: The armature seems fine but the mesh definetly doesn't]

Any tips? I've been looking for answers but none of them seem to help with my particular issue

Comment: Its possible you have the weights assigned twice. I would recommend separating your object out into its constituent elements as well. [extremely related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19313/character-made-with-multiple-objects-one-armature-or-different-armatures/19316#19316)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you apply the armature, make sure your character has no modifiers. You can check this by selecting the entire character and hitting [alt]+[c] and convert to mesh from curve/meta/etc. If you're getting an error message about bone heat weighting, make sure you remove all doubles (select all verts in edit mode and "remove doubles" in tools panel) and clear the normals [ctrl]+[n] in edit mode.

This is explained very well in the following video
[Blender-Fixing Automatic Weight Errors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZPqxADetWE)

If none of that worked, try separating the mesh into loose parts (select the entire mesh and [ctrl]+[p] in edit mode) and apply the armature while all the loose parts are still selected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check whether the mirror modifier is applied or not and if the armature modifier comes first in the modifiers tab of the object?

If there are any modifiers active except the armature modifier I would try to apply those first.

Also, you can change to weight painting mode and assign the bones manually to certain vertices. But you might know this already.